# NodeJS: How to handle a variable number of callbacks run in parallel and map their responses to requests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

As an exercise to teach myself more about node js I started making a basic CRUD REST server for SimpleDB (sdb) using the aws-sdk.

Everything was running smoothly until I got to a function for reading the domains.  The aws-sdk has two functions for this purpose: [listDomains](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SimpleDB_20090415.html#listDomains-property) and [domainMetadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SimpleDB_20090415.html#domainMetadata-property).  listDomains returns an array of sdb domain names.  domainMetadata will return additional statistics about a domain, but will only return them for one domain at a time.  It does not include the domain name in the results.

My script is running listDomains and returning an array in the JSON response just fine.  I would like to make my api readDomains function more ambitious though and have it return the metadata for all of the domains in the same single api call.  After all, running a handful of domainMetadata calls at the same time is where node's async io should shine.

The problem is I can't figure out how to run a variable number of calls, use the same callback for all of them, match the results of each domainMetadata call to it's domainName (since it's async and they're not guaranteed to return in the order they were requested) and tell when all of the metadata requests have finished so that I can send my final response.  Put into code my problem areas are:

```
domain.receiveDomainList = function(err, data){
 var domainList = [];

 for(var i=0; i<data.DomainNames.length; i++){
   sdb.domainMetaData({"DomainName":data.DomainNames[i]},domain.receiveMetadata);
   // alternatively:   domainList.push({"DomainName":data.DomainNames[i]});
 }
 // alternatively:  
 // async.map(domainList, sdb.domainMetadata, domain.receiveMetadata)

 console.log(domainList);
}

domain.receiveMetadata = function (err, data){
  // I figure I can stash the results one at a time in an array in the
  // parent scope but...

  // How can I tell when all of the results have been received?

  // Since the domainname used for the original call is not returned with 
  // the results how do I tell what result matches what request?
}
```

Based on my reading of async's readme the map function should at least match the metadata responses with the requests through some black magic, but it causes node to bomb out in the aws sync library with an error of " has no method 'makeRequest'".

Is there any way to have it all: requests run in parallel, requests matched with responses and knowing when I've received everything?

Comment: Check out promises or the [tag:async.js] library

Comment: Q and other promises run serially so I lose the big benefit of nodes async setup.

I tried async.map with no luck.  As I mentioned it caused an error in the aws-sdk.

async.parallel needs written with static function calls, thus won't work with a variable number of calls.  If I'm wrong could you provide a sample call in this context that would work?

Comment: You can create lots of parallel running promises and then wait for their results with [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/#combination). To both `Q.all` and [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async/#parallel) you can pass arrays with an arbitrary number of tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) you can set the context or `this` values as well as provide leading default arguments to the bound function.

The sample code below is purely to show how you might use `.bind()` to add additional context to your response callbacks.

In the code below, `.bind` is used to:

- set a `domainResults` object as the context for the `receiveMetaData` callback
- pass the current domain name as an argument to the callback

The `domainResults` object is used to:

- keep track of the number of names received in the first request
- keep track of the completedCount (incremented on each callback from the metaData request)
- keep track of both error and success responses in list
- provide a complete callback

Completely untested code for illustrative purposes only:

```
domain.receiveDomainList = function(err, data) {
    // Assuming err is falsey
    var domainResults = {
        nameCount: data.DomainNames.length,
        completeCount: 0,
        list: {},
        complete: function() {
            console.log(this.list);
        }
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < data.DomainNames.length; i++) {
        sdb.domainMetaData({ "DomainName": data.DomainNames[i] },
                             domain.receiveMetadata.bind(domainResults, data.DomainNames[i]));
    }
}

domain.receiveMetadata = function(domainName, err, data) {
    // Because of .bind, this === domainResults
    this.completeCount++;
    this.list[domainName] = data || {error: err};

    if(this.completeCount === this.nameCount) {
        this.complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  And as a bonus it keeps the code clean and avoids requiring an extra library.  Thanks!